# Color gamut in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode8, gamut

Today I have installed Xcode 8(beta) and exploring Storyboards. Here we can now set background and tintColor for different traits. That's good news.

But here with trait collection(for example any height X any width) there is another selection of `gamuts`

Here is the screenshot[image]

As I have searched for `gamut`, I found that it is related with color.
I have tried with different combination of `gamuts` but I am unable to see any difference.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/ColorGamutShowcase/Listings/README_md.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017308-README_md-DontLinkElementID_8) is also not helpful.

The question is how the developers get the benefit of this feature?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Developers can get benefit from it because it gives a much greater control over your app's color profile. You can explicitly assign a color to display depending on the device's gamut.

A solid understanding of gamut is key here. Devices will distort "untagged" colors, that is, colors outside of their gamut. The P3 gamut has a more extensive range of display colors than the sRGB gamut. This graph should give you a good idea of exactly how much more extensive it is:

[image: Gamut profiles]

So if you create your designs on a monitor with a P3 gamut, say a Cinema Display, your colors may display differently on a device with sRGB gamut. However, it's entirely possible there is no change in the color if you pick a color that is within both gamut.